# Is there a way to group desktop icons by user-defined types (drawing software, 3D software) and display a title above groups?

Tags: unity, icons

I'm managing some Ubuntu 16 machines for a Makerspace, and I'm trying to improve the user experience, particularly for less-experienced customers. Currently it's tough for the uninitiated to easily see the purpose or function of each of our applications without relying on extra reading material. We have 3D software (Blender, Cura), visual design software (GIMP, Krita, Inkscape) and other applications that can be grouped by purpose.

I'd like to display these on the desktop in visually distinct groupings with a title above each. I know this could be achieved by throwing the icons into named folders, but I want to tackle this with a more elegant solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: the launcher in unity pretty much does this for you. For example typing "image" with the filter set to applications will match GIMP, Shotwell, Image Viewer and etc. A different DE might also resolve your problem (Look at the menus in Ubuntu Studio for example)